# Unexpected Bar Chart in Plotly

Tags: plotly, data-science

This is the first time I'm doing something related to Data Science and I am completely stuck because I do not really understand why my bar chart looks like this:

[image]

When I expect it to actually look like this:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing, are there any configurations that I can make? [Here is the CSV file that I'm trying to plot.](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9f1824ef3b8f5b8aafffcb2bba78745d20191115130015/bccbd6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it looks like this is because you have many many short bars, and the outlines are overlapping. If you use `px.histogram` instead, the bars will get aggregated into combined bars.